# asp.net mvc 4 website is refusing to build on teamcity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, teamcity

I have a Windows Server 2003 box with teamcity that I use as a build/deployment server. I checked in a new asp.net mvc 4 project and it is crapping out with the following errors:

```
App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(2, 18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Controllers\AccountController.cs(8, 7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DotNetOpenAuth' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Global.asax.cs(7, 18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Models\AccountModels.cs(4, 45): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Schema' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

App_Start\BundleConfig.cs(9, 44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I've already installed asp.net mvc 4 on that box, restarted the machine and tried everything else without any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: those particular assemblies are not part of ASP.NET MVC 4, but separate downloads (i.e. nuget packages). Check if those nuget packages are part of the source that gets pulled down to the build server

Comment: What was the outcome of this? I have this problem too, package restore enabled, problems only on TC box.

Answer (score 2):

For me, my CI server (TeamCity) wouldn't take MVC 4 via the Web Platform Installer. Dunno why.

So I checked the TC build logs logs for the yellow warnings, looking for references its trying to resolve.

For each one, I then looked for the corresponding NuGet package in the project/solution and reinstalled it. This sets it up with package restore so that TeamCity/MSBuild restores it during build.

For example:

```
Update-Package WebGrease -Reinstall
```

The MVC project template, although it uses NuGet packages, they're not wired-into the whole package restore mechanism for some reason, so reinstalling them forces this. Effectively, I suppose you're installing MVC 4 via its constituent packages.

Luke

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would look in to:

1. Make sure that your NuGet packages are being pulled down appropriately during the build. [Documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages)
2. Make sure that the project is not still referencing the old MVC 3 assemblies somewhere. Perhaps a nant/msbuild build script is copying the old assemblies somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be helpful. But I had same problem. What I was trying to do is using EnableNuGetPackageRestore I was trying to restore it and some where it was causing problem (Restoring nuget packages from Test project rather than MVC project. I am not sure why but if I found out I will surely update thread). What I did is I followed blog from http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/08/nuget-package-restore-with-teamcity/. Adding one more build step NuGet Installer helped me fix issue. (Caution: If you are using internal nuget package server than you need to specify same in Sources). Please let me know if you have still problem and I can be of any help. Happy Building !!

Comment: I had a similar issue. You will need to access bin folder from your project folder and delete it manually. After that Build the app again(its what clean solution option does). After that you will see all the same errors in your local enviroment so you can fix them easily. You can also verufy that the csproj file for your solution is well configured by watching all the references are pointing to directories that do exist in your machine (This may potentially happen if you have changed/reordered the directories were your solution files were first created).